# Is it possible to run some script on each npm install event?

Tags: javascript, npm

I want to install pre-push hooks for git on each `npm install` event. Is it possible? Maybe is there some alternative solution? By the way I don't want to install stuff like gulp, I want to use only npm.

Comment: `postinstall` script? https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: @Matt yes this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do something like this:

in your **package.json** file you can add install hooks like so:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "install": "scripts/install.js",
    "postinstall": "scripts/postinstall.js",
    "uninstall": "scripts/uninstall.js"
  }
}
```

the **postinstall.js** will be executed after you install a package. Having this in mind, you can create a **shell** script which can do the git push's for you.

Is this something you are looking for?